# Best known bounds on the error term for the average order of the sum-of-divisors function

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I'm doing some research for a paper I'm writing and I can't seem to find a good non-classical bound for the error term in the following sum (cf. Hardy and Wright):
$$\sum_{n \leq x} \sigma_1(n) = \frac{\pi^2}{12} x^2 + O(x \log x).$$ 
There seem to be many references in a bibliographic search for the corresponding error term in the same sum over the divisor function $d(n) = \sigma_0(n)$, but I'm not having any luck finding a good more modern reference for the case above. I have a friend who claims that you can improve the error term to something like $O(x^{1/3} \log x)$ using modular forms and the hyperbolic method, but these details are still fuzzy to me. Can anyone suggest a reference to the best currently known error terms for this sum? Much appreciated.

Comment: Your friend probably confused it with the summatory function of $\sigma_0$. Since the Dirichlet series of $\sigma_1$ - $\zeta(s)\zeta(s-1)$ - has a pole at $1$, the error term _cannot_ be of order $x^{1-\varepsilon}$ for an $\varepsilon > 0$.

Comment: I thought that might be the case too. Does this mean that the classical bound is optimal, i.e., we cannot do better than $O(x \log x)$?

Comment: Since $$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sigma_1(n)}{n \log \log n} = e^{\gamma}\,,$$ no continuous function can approximate $\sum_{n \leqslant x} \sigma_1(n)$ with an error of smaller order than $O(x\log \log x)$. I wouldn't be surprised if that's the actual order of the error, but neither would I be surprised if it's $O\bigl(x(\log x)^{\alpha}\bigr)$ for some $\alpha > 0$. (But I would be surprised if somebody could prove the actual order within the next fifty years.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best known result is due to Walfisz (Walfisz, A. -- Weylsche Exponentialsummen in der neueren Zahlentheorie -- 1963 -- approximately on page 100). He proves that

$$\sum_{n \leq X} \sigma_1(n) = \frac{\pi^2}{12}X^2 + O(X (\log X)^{2/3}).$$

The error term cannot possibly be improved past $O(X)$ without introducing a secondary leading term, and it is quite unlikely that one could extract two main terms and an error term of size approximately $O(X^{1/3})$. I would guess that your friend is confused. (If not, then your friend should publish a paper).